# How would you make sure a list of 40,000 contacts is up to date?

Tags: python, parsing, data-cleaning

I'm still new at programming (Python) and a little overwhelmed with the task of updating a list of about 40,000 contacts. Obviously, I don't want to do this manually and am trying to figure out how to best automate the task. Any advice or help pointing in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Here are the issues:

1. I need to make sure that the info is still up to date (i.e. that the person still works at the same company and/or hasn't changed his job title). What would be the best way to do it? Parse LinkedIn? Try to find their Facebook profiles and hope they disclose where they work?
2. For some contacts I only have an email and company name (maybe a job title), but not the person's name. Is there a way to get the first and last names with the information I have and how would you do it?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an impossible task because

1: the information out there could be incorrect

2: there are often multiple people with the same name so how would you identify them

3: even if someone has stopped working at a company they will have traces of that fact online and

4: you won't be able to find someone's name from their email unless it's literally a substring of their name i.e. first.lastname@company.com.

If you want to start somewhere I would say work with the email name parsing. If you want to branch out into hardcore webscraping you can try but this will not be a small task. You'll need to build a different interface for each platform and you will need some kind of logic to find former vs. current which may not be stored in a nice format. If you want somewhere to start on that front check out:

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-linkedin/4.0

and maybe look for your country's version of yell, 118 etc. which may have a REST api or JSON interface

Comment: Thanks! What if I sent out an email to the 40,000 contacts to see which ones bounce back? That could shorten the list and show which contacts are definitely outdated. You can assume that if an email works then the person still works there in the same position or similar capacity.

I could then scrape data from LinkedIn and cross-reference it with what I already have. I.e., get info on everyone who works for Acme Corp and then look at all John Smiths that work there and that are on my list. Chances are there won't be that many matches, especially if a person has a unique first or last name

Comment: Yeah you could definitely ping off an email to everyone but you will want to make sure it's not spam (if it's treated as such you might have issues with the response code). What you're suggesting for Linkedin is what I was considering. Again it will be a matter of working out who is past/present but that information is on the website. Bear in mind that big companies will probably have a high level of duplicates so you may want to test whether person's period of employment includes the time when the data was correct.